# How i can send image files with discord.File in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how i can send 3 image files?
Because thats not works..

```
@bot.command()
async def image_file(ctx):
   await ctx.send(file=discord.File("--.png", "---.png", "----.png"))
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `files` instead of `file`, and create a `discord.File` for each image, so:

```py
@bot.command()
async def image_file(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send(files=[discord.File("-.png"), discord.File("--.png"), discord.File("---.png")])
```